# How to display the previous page if the lastpart id / page is not found?

Tags: php, .htaccess

How can i show the given page insted of main index file?

in my url `https://learnpk.xyz/view/88` it shows `https://learnpk.xyz/index.php` but
i want to show page `https://learnpk.xyz/view.php`

i am using below commands in `.htaccess` file.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try these rules in your site root .htaccess:

```bash
RewriteEngine On

# show /view.php for /view/88 provided .php file exists
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)(?:/|$) $1.php [L]

# rewrite all non-files, non-directories to /index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```